# SSIS mapping columns with different data

Tags: mapping, ssis

I am trying to write a SSIS package to transfer data from a flat file into my database. My lookup column in the DB table has the names "BUY", "SELL", "BUY COVER", "SHORT SELL", and "POSITION ADJUSTMENT". The data I am mapping to this table has "BUY", "SELL", "COVER", and "SHORT", respectively.

How do I get the mappings to recognize that "BUY COVER"/"COVER" and "SHORT SELL"/"SHORT" should be matched up? How do I transform the incoming data to be applicable to my DB requirements?

Using Visual Studio Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide those mappings, much as I described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022885/ssis-sql-server-2008/17025568#17025568). For all of your possible inputs, you need to create a translation to the reference value---same as if you were doing this in SQL or anything else.

Comment: Thanks, @billinkc. I ended up doing something different, but that's a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something different to solve this problem. Since I just wanted to be able to map from columns in the flat file to the database, I did the following and it works just fine.

In the Lookup Transformation Editor I inserted the following query into the SQL Query option for the lookup:

select cast (TradeTypeId as int) as TradeTypeId, 
TradeType =
case
when TradeTypeId = 3 then 'COVER'
when TradeTypeId = 4 then 'SHORT'
else TradeTypeName
end
from dbo.sct_TradeType
where TradeTypeId<> 9

The "TradeType" holds the values "BUY", "SELL", "BUY COVER", "SHORT SELL", and "POSITION ADJUSTMENT". I am not using "POSITION ADJUSTMENT" (id =9) so it's eliminated from the query at the end. This converted my file column names to match my database names and everything works!