# How do I create this SSIS lookup in SSDT for VS 2012?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a column in my data source named "Gender". Currently the column contains one of six possible values. I want to create a transformation that takes the value from the source and converts it to one of four standardardized values. How do I do this?

So far I added the lookup transformation to the designer surface and checked the options. I think I can accomplish this with a simple SQL query, psuedocode below, but I'm not sure what I need to do or how to do it.

```
If Gender = M or Gender = 1 then GenderId = 1
If Gender = F or Gender = 2 then GenderId = 2
If Gender = U then GenderId = 3
If Gender = X then GenderId = 4
... etc.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As I referenced in a similar question, [SSIS (SQL Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022885/ssis-sql-server-2008/17025568#17025568)

### Option 1

A derived column but that's going to get a little ugly due to line length.

### Option 2

A lookup transformation where you map your source Gender column to the lookup's

```
SELECT D.Gender, D.GenderId
FROM
(
    SELECT 'M', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT '1', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 'F', 2
    --- etc
) D (Gender, GenderId);
```

### Option 3

Fix it in the source query. If you're pulling this data out of a database, use a CASE statement there to coerce the value of GenderId into the correct thing so you can simplify your package.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx) to make a new StandardizedGender column.  You can use immediate if statements (?: syntax) to build the case structure.  Derived Columns are usually your best tool for handling this sort of conversion and cleanup.

Comment: I see the new column should be called GenderId, not StandardizedGender.

Answer (score 0):

If the data source is an SQL database, suggest working it out in an SQL query with a CASE statement. You should see some performance benefits too.